# How do I detect requests initiated by the new fetch standard? How should I detect an AJAX request in general?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

On a server it can be useful to know that an incoming request is AJAX.

Most js libraries use `XMLHttpRequest` and so provide `HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH: XMLHttpRequest`, but neither Chrome's implementation nor [Github's polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch) of the new [`fetch`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org) uses a similar header. So how can one detect that the request is AJAX?

Why is a request identifying its initiator not enforced through standards for `fetch` and `XMLHttpRequest`? Should something else be used for decision-making (e.g. clients providing the content-type they expect in response)?

Comment: You cannot reliably detect this for arbitrary clients. If you control the client, you can add some parameter, path element or header. Ideally, you should not need to, though. If the request needs to be treated differently somehow, the client should clearly indicate which option is appropriate (for example by having separate URL paths for AJAX and page loads).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check out [this issue](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/17) on the [Github's polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch) repository, specially [this](https://github.com/github/fetch/issues/17#issuecomment-59634024) comment.

Since the `X-Requested-With` header is not an standard, they are using a wrapper that provides some of the missing behavior.

If you need more guidance, check [this lines](https://gist.github.com/dgraham/92e4c45da3707a3fe789#file-fetch-js-L12-L17) of the wrapper code:

```
function headers(options) {
  options = options || {}
  options.headers = options.headers || {}
  options.headers['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest'
  return options
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a concrete example to set an HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH header:

```
fetch("/url", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why is a request identifying its initiator not enforced through standards

Because it shouldn't matter.

HTTP clients ask for the thing they want to get. The server should give it to them.

Giving clients something different based on what the client is tends to cause more problems than it solves. User-Agent sniffing being a prime example.

> Should something else be used for decision-making (e.g. clients providing the content-type they expect in response)?

Yes.

The `Accept` header is specifically provided for allowing a client to specify which format they would prefer the data in when an HTTP resource is available in multiple formats.

Comment: Single Page applications can request HTML via AJAX so an Accept header would be indistinguishable from a non AJAX request....

However Redirects are where this problem comes to a head, specifically in handling 401 to an external identity provider.

i.e. Server application code raises a 401 => Authentication handler converts to 301 => browser follows and navigates window.

If the request was an AJAX request, then the browser won't navigate but the fetch/XMLHttpRequest will follow.  The server needs to send back a 401

Comment: I agree returning a 401 instead of a 301 is a big problem without being able to tell if the request is ajax or fetch for most server side frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

A new answer is that most browsers now support the `Sec-Fetch-Mode` header, which has these options:

- `Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors`
- `Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate`
- `Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors`
- `Sec-Fetch-Mode: same-origin`
- `Sec-Fetch-Mode: websocket`

Depending on your use-case, ajax is any request other than `navigate`, or other than `navigate` or `websocket`. You could use this conditional if it exists, and fallback to `X_REQUESTED_WITH` otherwise. Or for some situations looking at `Sec-Fetch-Mode` might give you confidence in enough situations that you can just have a default for the other cases.

How to check it — look at the headers on the backend, eg in express.js it would be:

`headers['sec-fetch-mode'] == 'navigate'`

[Source: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Sec-Fetch-Mode)

Comment: This header has nothing whatsoever to do with whether or not the requests have been made using the Fetch API in JavaScript.  It can be changed by using XMLHttpRequest *or* the Fetch API.

Comment: I didn't say it had anything to do with the Fetch API, I just said that browsers send it!